# Updating Database Using SQLite3 via Swift results in misuse

Tags: swift, sqlite

Trying to UPDATE database using SQLite3 under the function updateBankItem, but I keep getting a misuse in the debugger below. I'm not sure how I am misusing SQLite3.

> 2023-01-06 16:32:00.872219-0600 L2S Bank Manager[18960:1066654] [logging] misuse at line 94051 of [554764a6e7]

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3


class DBHelper {
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "L2SDB", ofType: "sqlite")
    
    init() {
        self.db = setupDB()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: SQL Stuff
    func setupDB() -> OpaquePointer? {
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_open(path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
            return nil
        } else {
            return db
        }
    }
    //This handles the Nil Assuming Blanks
    func sqlColumnText(statement: OpaquePointer?, column: Int32) -> String {
        if sqlite3_column_text(statement, column) == nil {
            return ""
        } else {
            return String(describing:  String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, column)))
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: For Loading Indivdual Subjects
    func loadQuestionBank(forBank bankIdentifier: String) -> BankWithIdentifier {
        var questions = [MultipleChoiceQuestion]()
        //New SQL Way
        let query = "SELECT * FROM \(bankIdentifier);"
        var statement : OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
                let number = Int(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0))
                let question = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 1)
                let answers = [
                    sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 2),
                    sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 3),
                    sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 4),
                    sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 5)
                    ]
                let correctAnswer = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 6)
                let illustration = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 7)
                let solution = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 8)
                let questionID = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 9)
                let category = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 10)
                let subCategory = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 11)
                let specifier = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 12)
                let subSubject = sqlColumnText(statement: statement, column: 13)
                
                let model = MultipleChoiceQuestion(number: number, question: question, correctAnswer: correctAnswer, answers: answers, illustration: illustration, solution: solution, questionID: questionID, category: category, subCategory: subCategory, specifier: specifier, subSubject: subSubject)
                
                questions.append(model)
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement)
        }
        return BankWithIdentifier(bankIdentifier: bankIdentifier, questionBank: questions)
    }
    
    public func updateBankItem(number: Int, question: String, answers: [String], correct: String, illustration: String, solution: String, questionID: String, category: String, subCategory: String, specifier: String, subSubject: String ){
        
        var bankIdentifier = String()
        for subject in Subjects().combinedSubjects() {
            let bank = loadQuestionBank(forBank: subject.bankIdentifier)
            if bank.questionBank.contains(where: {$0.questionID == questionID}) {
                bankIdentifier = subject.bankIdentifier
                break
            }
        }
        
        let query = "UPDATE \(bankIdentifier) SET number = \(number), question = '\(question)', ansA = '\(answers[0])', ansB = '\(answers[1])', ansC = '\(answers[2])', ansD = '\(answers[3])', correctAnswer = '\(correct)', illustration = '\(illustration)', solution = '\(solution)', questionID = '\(questionID)', category = '\(category)', subCategory = '\(subCategory)', specifier = '\(specifier)', subSubject = '\(subSubject)' WHERE questionID = '\(questionID)';"
        
        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
                if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
                    print("Question Updated Success")
                } else {
                    print("Question Update Failed")
                    print("Statement \(sqlite3_step(statement))")
                }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }
    
}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Print `query` (or run the debugger) to verify it’s a proper sql statement

Comment: The query is correct with no syntax errors. I printed the Query and then tested in DB Browser and the data was successfully changed. Just can't figure out why it won't work using SQLite3 in Xcode.

Comment: One things that looks strange with the query is that you are updating the same attribute you use in the WHERE condition, that is `questionID`. Wether this is the cause of the problem or not I think you should really consider if this is what you want to do since it could possibly lead to other issues down the road.

Comment: Which line of code in `updateBankItem` is actually causing the "misuse" logging statement to appear?

Comment: Side notes - 1) it's a terrible idea to build a query using string interpolation. You really should properly bind values (using `sqlite3_bind_xxx`) into an "update" or "insert" statement. 2) It's also a terrible idea to use "SELECT *". Explicitly list the fields you wish to select. This ensure you get the correct fields in the correct order expected by your code.